# Sort rows of matrix based on array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix

My code try to sort a matrix based on an array, firts i try to sort the array from lowest to highest, the number of elements inside array are directly proportional to the number of rows in the matrix, so when i do bubblesort of the array, i want the same bubblesort in the matrix.

The code sort correctly the array, but the matrix is a mess.

```
matriz = np.array(([4, 1, 6, 9], [1, 3, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0, 2], [1, 1, 4, 5], [2, 1, 4, 1]))
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    n = int(len(matrix[i]))
    for j in range(n):
        average[i] += (matrix[i][j]/n)

print(average)
for a in range(len(average)-1):
    for b in range(a+1, len(average)):
        if average[a] > average[b]:
            aux = average[a]
            average[a] = average[b]
            average[b] = aux
            auxMatrix = matrix[a]
            matrix[a] = matrix[b]
            matrix[b] = auxMatrix

print(average)
print(matrix)
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Please give a [mre]. Your current example code has typos / is missing definitions / is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using numpy you might as well use its efficient functions:

```
sorted_matrix = matrix[np.argsort(matrix.mean(axis=1))]
```